# Separator between PHP echo statements if required

Tags: php, echo, separator

How do I display a separator between elements if a separator is required?  I need to display a name, job title, and company if each of those appears in a news quote entry.

Not all news quotes have all three items, it could be:

1. name, job title, company
2. name, job title
3. name, company
4. name

For each variation, I need to echo a separator such as , or |

Currently the query is this:

```
<?php echo $row_article['quote_name'] . ', ' . $row_article['quote_job'] . ', ' . $row_article['quote_company']; ?>
```

Which if all three exist, it looks correct.  But if only any two exist I get something like:

```
name, , company
, job title, company
name, job title,
```

Comment: Each `$row_article` contais all items, but they may be blank.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use a combination of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [implode](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

I'll write up an example.

```
<?php

$delimiter = ' | ';

$row_articles = array(
  array(
    'quote_name' => 'Foo',
    'quote_job' => 'Bar',
    'quote_company' =>'Baz'
  ),
  array(
    'quote_name' => 'Foo',
    'quote_job' => 'Bar',
    'quote_company' =>''
  ),
  array(
    'quote_name' => 'Foo',
    'quote_job' => '',
    'quote_company' =>'Baz'
  ),
  array(
    'quote_name' => 'Foo',
    'quote_job' => '',
    'quote_company' =>''
  ),
);


foreach ($row_articles as $row_article) {
  echo implode($delimiter, array_filter($row_article));
  echo "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Foo | Bar | Baz
Foo | Bar
Foo | Baz
Foo
```

Comment: @artragis: Is that a question?  If so, then yes - that is how implode works.

Comment: I wrote this message 2 seconds before your edit, so sorry if it repeats what you said.

Answer (score 2):

[implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is your friend.

Add each of the items to a holding array and then join them up using implode(", ", array_name).

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to put them in an array

```
$arr[] = $var1;
$arr[] = $var2;
$arr[] = $var3;

$newarr = array_filter($arr);

echo implode(',', $newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
echo implode( ', ', $row_article);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the php implode method like this.

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

// Empty string when using an empty array:
var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""

?>
```